# How to deploy multiple NodeJS applications on different subdomains in digital ocean

Tags: node.js, nginx, subdomain, digital-ocean

Hie guys, So earlier I deployed a nodejs application that run on one port but using Nginx, I can still accept requests on default HTTP/HTTPS ports and forward them to my application's port. Now I would like to deploy an admin part of the same application which was built in its own project space and is running on a lightly different port as my client application; and I would like to assign this to a subdomain.

I am running an Ubuntu distribution on Digital Ocean. How can I accomplish this?

Below is my entire nginx config:

```
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {

    # SSL configuration
    

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; #whatever port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}






# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
server {
 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name admin.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #whatever port your app runs on
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {

    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;   listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

My admin Node App is running on port 3000 and Client App on 5000

Comment: What have you tried here. Because if you can accept requests (`server_name domain.com`) and forward requests to default port already (`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80`), surely you must have tried `server_name sub.domain.com` and `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081`?

Comment: And the point here is not that to say that "it's so easy, how can you struggle with this?" (sorry if that's what it sounded like). Just that if you show your config you'll get concise and specfic answers, but now we have to guess instead.

Comment: I understand. So the thing is before recently, I had never actually deployed an application on Linux. This was my first time to deploy any application on a fully self managed server. The instruction I followed can be found here : https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cd90d1ed3c462fe3bddd11bf8953a896 . It was not so apparent that I could repeate the part of the config that you have highlighted

Comment: So your problem is resolved? Usually you repeat the entire server-block. For example like this: https://serverfault.com/a/538831/233631

Comment: Not really @ippi. ```admin.mydomain.com``` is still redirecting to the app running on the other PORT. I have edited the question to include the server block that I have added. Please check it out. Maybe its misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx configuration looks ok, in order to achieve the desired result, you have to add a new dns resolution for your new domain in digital ocean panel.

Add a new cname record that is an alias for your domain, as follow:

```
CNAME admin.mydomain.com 
is an alias of mydomain.com
```

1. Digital ocean panel
2. Networking
3. DNS records
4. Create new record **`cname`** type

This configuration must match your current nginx configuration for the `server_name` atribute.

Comment: I have done this, but stiil not working. I have again edited the question to include my entire config file. Maybe there is something